# Perform Segue with Identifier is slow in Show (e.g Push) mode

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am doing Storyboard app in Xcode 8, swift 3.
The problem is that performSegue(withIdentifier is slow.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()    
   print("segue")
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "openFeedbackForm", sender: "123")
}
```

After "segue" is printed it takes about 2-3 seconds for segue to perform. It is very irritating in other parts of the application. Have no idea what is the problem. Programmaticall approach has no problems.

BTW, I have no code in prepare for Segue.

EDIT:
I tried to create new empty view controller and perform segue to it. It is fast as expected. So I guess slow part is with loading my view controller. But there is no networking etc. Only things I do in my slow segue view controller is creating buttons, labels, text fields etc. Why can be it slow?
Here is my code in slow segue controller:

```js
import UIKit

class FeedbackFormViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var hashTagTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextField: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendFeedbackButton: UIButton!
    
    var branchId: String = ""
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // set navigation bar title image
        self.navigationItem.titleView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "bagala-logo"))
        self.navigationItem.titleView?.tintColor = UIColor.white
        hashTagTextField.delegate = self
        descriptionTextField.delegate = self
        print(self.branchId)
        
        // fix button at the botoom of screen
        sendFeedbackButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: self.view.bounds.height-54.0,
                                          width:self.view.bounds.width,
                                          height: 54)
    }

    // MARK: - UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
    // MARK: - UITextViewDelegate
    func textViewShouldEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        textView.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    
    func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }


}
```

As you can see no networking, threading etc.

Comment: Try in viewWillAppear rather than viewDidLoad

Comment: @Paulw11, but segue is slow in any part. I mean if i attach segue to some button click, it is slow to.

Comment: Are you using custom font?  Is it slow if you run without the debugger?  Are you doing anything in a background queue? Fetching network data?

Comment: @Paulw11, no I'v just created xcode 8 app. It has no networking, only some labels, text fields etc.